# multiply sequence by float

Tags: python, arrays, sequence

New to python, and can't seem to figure out how to multiply the list pounds with the conversion factor for kilograms. This assignment also needs arrays so did the best I could, any tips would be appreciated!

```
def main():
    welcome()

    get_pounds()

    
    
def welcome():
    print(" This program takes pounds, provides average, sum and converts to kilograms. ")

def get_pounds():
    pounds = list()
    amount = eval(input("Please enter pounds, enter -1 to exit"))
    while (amount != -1):
        pounds.append(amount)

        amount = eval(input("Please enter pounds, enter -1 to exit"))

    average = sum(pounds)/len(pounds)
    print("sum of numbers: ", sum(pounds))
    print("Average pounds: ", average)

   
    kilogram = 0.5 #per pound

    for kilogram in pounds:
        conversion = 0.5 * pounds
        conversion.append(kilogram)
        print("In kilograms: ",kilogram)

    
        

    

main()
```

Comment: Side-note: Never use `eval` for this purpose (imagine the effect of input like `"__import__('shutil').rmtree('/')"`). In this case you probably want `float` (or `int` if they're only allowed to enter a whole number worth of pounds). For accepting arbitrary Python literals, you want `ast.literal_eval` (that only evaluates legal literals, not arbitrary code).

Comment: Take the input from the user as a string, and then [parse that string to a float or int](//stackoverflow.com/q/379906/843953). Also, I suggest redoing a tutorial on how loops work. When you do `for some_var in some_list`, in each iteration of your loop, the `some_var` variable contains the current value from `some_list` that is being iterated over.

Comment: In any event, your final loop makes no sense. You iterate over the `list` of pound values, call each value that represents a value in pounds `kilogram`(??), ignore it to try to multiply the `list` of pound values itself by `0.5`(???) to compute `conversion`, then act like `conversion` is a `list` and try to append the unmodified `kilogram` (that's really a value in pounds) to it (??!!??). Think through the logic there, literally nothing in that makes sense.

Comment: Use list comprehension: `kilograms = [pound * kilogram for pound in pounds]`

Comment: Also read through [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) (particularly the part on rubber-duck debugging) and
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953). Being able to understand what your program does, and how it differs from what you expect it to do is an important part of programming

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are trying to do with the list. This solves the problem i think. When you do: for i in alist, you iterate through the list and for every item in it, you set i equal to the item. you also defined conversion as 0.5*kilograms, and then redefined it to a list when you said conversion.append(kilogram).

```
kilogram = 0.5 #per pound
kilograms_list = [] 
for i in pounds:
 conversion = 0.5 * i
 kilograms_list.append(conversion)
 print("In kilograms: ",conversion)
```